# New computers: migration from Windows 7 to Windows 10 with user data

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, sync

I have this situation

20 new computers with Windows 10 64 Pro.
20 old computers with Windows 7 64 Pro.

In each old computer there is only one main user that I need to migrate to the new computer. All of his/her data and configs (300GB per computer)

There is no roaming profile and no additional space in servers to move the data. Ah, and I cannot open the new computers if I want to keep the warranty.

At the moment I tried:

1. BTSync. It's slow as hell and the old computers goes slow.
2. Power off the old computer, plug the old HDD into the new computer, run a linux live CD and rsync files. Works great but lot of downtime for the user.

Anyone knows a better way to do that in this scenario where I cannot expend money on fancy software? I'm thinking on go with the second option but working off hours, so I don't bother people.

Comment: Would you be able to test with one of these solutions: http://www.easeus.com/pc-transfer/windows-easy-transfer-7-to-10.html Not 100% certain if applicable in your particular case but I thought I'd at least run by you.

Comment: Since you have such large restraints.  Log into the built-in Administrator user,  take ownership of each user's profile, and copy the data to an external drive.  Just a matter of transferring the data to the new computers as the user, on the new computer,  at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at Laplink for personal use, and Tranxition Migration Manager for IT use. It really makes sense to go with a commercial solution.